# SQLite delete all rows where not equal "stage!=? " in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am try to delete row from SQLite database on my apps.
This code for "Where field value equal"

```
mydatabase.delete("potentials", "stage=?", new String[]{"Ready for Install"});
```

But I need "Where field value not equal"

```
mydatabase.delete("potentials", "stage!=?", new String[]{"Ready for Install"});
```

And

```
 mydatabase.delete("potentials", "stage<>?", new String[]{"Ready for Install"});
```

I tried this code, but it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this function:

```
public void DeletePostbyId(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_CHECK + " WHERE " + ID + "!='" + id + "'");
        db.close();

        //db.delete(TABLE_CAT, CAT_ID + "= ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(catid)});
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use in the comparator the non-equal operator: "stage!=?" or "stage<>?".

mydatabase.delete("potentials", "stage<>?", new String[]{"Ready for Install"});

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your query. The reason why it may fail here is letter case... Try this

`mydatabase.delete("potentials", "upper(stage) != ?", new String[]{"READY FOR INSTALL"});`

Also notice the spacing near `upper(stage)`